# What is the difference between a cell and a row in table view?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I often use table views in my application but I don't have a clear understanding of the difference between a cell and a row. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A dictionary is the best help for your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> didn't get the clear difference between cell and row

Rows contain cells. Cells contain labels, images, etc.

There are as many rows as your data source items. Cells are reused and shown only in rows that are visible.

Answer (score 2):

A row is a place: e.g., section 0, row 3. It's a concept.

A cell is what goes into a row, e.g. a UITableViewCell. It's a view (a thing the user can see and touch).

Comment: I think row can also be selected ( ex. tableView(_:willSelectRowAt:) ), please correct me if I'm wrong